# I have a code and need to check if the column is null or contains wrong data through try catch

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, epplus

I have written some code and in it, a foreach brings all data within excel columns...
But I want to find if the Excel File contains any null column(CELL) or any other data Type that might give an error when storing it in database

When the Excel contains a blank cell, the foreach loops skips that column and I'm not able to put any condition to check the blank value over there

```cs
    using OfficeOpenXml;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;



    public static class ExcelPackageExtensions
    {
     public static DataTable ToDataTable(this ExcelPackage package)
     {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }

        for (var rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        {
            var row = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
            var newRow = dt.NewRow();


                foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    if (cell.Start.Column == 2)//when col2 has no data in excel foreach skips and i'm not able to check the null value 
                    {
                        if (cell.Text == null)
                        { goto End; }
                    }
                    if (cell.Start.Column == 3)
                    {
                        if (cell.Text == null)
                        { goto End; }
                    }
                    if (cell.Start.Column == 18)
                    {
                        string datefromtemp = Convert.ToString(cell.Text);
                        DateTime datefromtemp2 = Convert.ToDateTime(datefromtemp, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = datefromtemp2;
                    }
                    else if (cell.Start.Column == 19)
                    {
                        string datetotemp = Convert.ToString(cell.Text);
                        DateTime datetotemp2 = Convert.ToDateTime(datetotemp, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = datetotemp2;
                    }
                    else if (cell.Start.Column == 21)
                    {
                        string createddatetemp = Convert.ToString(cell.Text);
                        DateTime createddatetemp2 = Convert.ToDateTime(createddatetemp, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = createddatetemp2;
                    }
                    else if (cell.Start.Column == 23)
                    {
                        string modifieddatetemp = Convert.ToString(cell.Text);
                        DateTime modifieddatetemp2 = Convert.ToDateTime(modifieddatetemp, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = modifieddatetemp2;
                    }
                    else if (cell.Start.Column == 24)
                    {
                        int isactivetemp = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Text);
                        bool isactivetemp2 = Convert.ToBoolean(isactivetemp);
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = isactivetemp2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                    }
                }
        End:
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    }
```

Comment: I'll have a quick look but might I suggest using `break` to get out of the loot as opposed to `goto End;`

Comment: Using "Label" in C# is a bad idea, change all "GOTO"s to "dt.Rows.Add(newRow);"

Comment: Also, do you mean "Check all column in excel sheet" and see if any field is null? second, "or any other data Type that might give an error when storing it in database" <-- It depends on the database datatype, for example, you would need to store integer into a column type of int in MSSQL. Do you mean, the expected datatype of column 18-21, 23 is date time, the expected type of column 24 is boolean?

Comment: Did you try String.IsNullOrEmpty(); ?